# Can you identify this plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

The one on the left with purple daisy-like looking flowers. It has bulbs growing near the roots.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a single-flowered dahlia to me. Google "single dahlia" and select "images" to compare the flowers.

The "bulbs" are actually rhizomes, not true bulbs. They are swollen roots which store nutrients over winter when the foliage dies.

The plant on the right looks like a chrysanthemum.